# Temp table of numbers that do not exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called **UsedNumbers**

**UsedNumbers** contains number in the range of **1 AND 9999**. 
The numbers are can be anywhere in this range.

I want to create a temp table **#UnUsedNumbers**.

So far I found code create a range of numbers from 1 to 9999. But I'm not entirely sure how to **INSERT** this into a temp table and then extract only the numbers that do not exist in **UsedNumbers**.

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT TOP (224) [OBJECT_ID] FROM sys.all_objects
)
SELECT TOP (9999) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.[object_id])
FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS y
ORDER BY n;
```

I would love to understand more about this if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT TOP (224) [OBJECT_ID] FROM sys.all_objects
)
SELECT TOP (9999) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.[object_id])
FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS y
EXCEPT 
SELECT num
FROM UsedNumbers
ORDER BY n
```

Comment: Thanks! that definitely creates the list I want - Sorry, I'm a little new to this. How do I use the data now? Do I still need to put this in a temptable to call it? I need to pull the information into a pass-through query in MS Access.

Comment: @cocojay you should be able to write this directly in the pass thru query

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
;WITH NumberCTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP (224) [OBJECT_ID] FROM sys.all_objects
)
,
AllNumbersCTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP (9999)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by RS1.[OBJECT_ID]) AS ROWID
    FROM 
        NumberCTE AS RS1
    LEFT JOIN NumberCTE AS RS2 ON 1 = 1
)

SELECT ROWID FROM AllNumbersCTE WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT Number FROM UsedNumbers)
```